# How can I "stretch" a lower resolution image to fit fullscreen in godot?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I am trying to make a resolution change option in gdscript. Default resolution is 1920x1080, but when I change it to 1280x720 while in fullscreen using this line of code:

```
get_viewport().size = Vector2(1280 , 720)
```

the image shrinks to the to the top left of my screen. I want it to be like a fullscreen youtube video when I change to 720p from 1080p. Lower resolution but it stretches to the whole screen.

At first I though I needed to change my settings at Project Settings/Display/Window/Stretch. I tried different combinations but that doesn't help. Currently I use Mode:viewport/aspect:keep/scale:1